# Retrieving file from a symbolic link folder

Tags: linux, coldfusion, jboss, symlink

I have a folder containing an image (`http://myserver/originalfolder/test.jpg`) hosted on my server running on Suse 11.1. I also have a symbolic link to this folder within my coldfusion instance (`http://myserver/cfusion/myinstance/shortcutfolder`), running on JBoss, pointing to the original folder.

When I check for file existence by typing in the url `http://myserver/cfusion/myinstance/shortcutfolder/test.jpg` in the browser, I am getting a 404 error. However when I tried the same procedure with a .cfm file, it worked perfectly. It seems that there is some kind of filter somewhere.

Is there any way to retrieve a non .cfm through a symbolic link from my coldfusion application please?

Comment: HTTP doesn't understand "files" or "short-cuts", just URLs. Are you talking about HTTP redirections?

Comment: Created with the Windows explorer?

Comment: Apache under linux has the option `FollowSymlinks`, I guess you need the Windows equivalent for your Server.

Comment: I'm using coldfusion with JBoss. This might be a coldfusion issue, as I managed to access cfm files but not jpg files

Comment: What do you get if you just *browse* to the URLs in question? Do the results not match what you are seeing via your function?

Comment: When I try to access the image in the original folder via URL, all works well. However, if I try to access the image via the folder with a symbolic link to the original folder, I get a 404 error.

Comment: But what do you get when you browse `http://myserver/cfusion/myinstance/shortcutfolder`?

Comment: I get a coldfusion error, that index.cfm doesn't exist. That's why I added the update above. I created the file 'index.cfm' in the original folder, and I managed to access it. However, I didn't manage to access an image

Comment: So it sounds to me less like you have a problem with your function returning correct results, and more like your web server doesn't know about that symlink you created. Can you pls clarify what it is you're asking? Which web server are you using? Also, when you say you created a symlink in Windows Explorer... you def don't mean a *shortcut*, right? You actually made a proper link? Didn't know one could do that in Win Explorer! Which version of Windows?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Yes, I created a symbolic link between the two folders (shortcutfolder --> originalfolder). The problem is that I managed to access the contents directly from `originalfolder` but not from the linked folder `shortcutfolder`

Comment: Hang on. Are you creating a SHORTCUT (ie: right-click on a dir and going "create shortcut"), or creating an actual *link*? Because those are two different things. And a *shortcut* is just "navigational sugar" for Windows Explorer, and not even remotely the same as a symlink or a directory junction. And I'd be very surprised if a web server or a CF server would know what to do with a Windows Explorer shortcut.

Comment: @AdamCameron, no i created a symbolink link using the command prompt. And I am not using windows, but Linux Suse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of a symbolic link, I mounted the folder containing the images on my server to another folder in my coldfusion instance using the command:

```
mount --bind olddir newdir
```

Answer (score 3):

Adding a shortcut folder in the top level directory of your default website in IIS is not supported so you need to add a virtual directory to the default website pointing to the folder you want instead. See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/172138

Comment: Your web server application should have a specific way to add a directory to it (that is not already under the current root) for serving. Please search for your web server name + 'virtual directory' or 'add directory' and you should see what you need to do.

Comment: Virtual directory is far better than symlink.